# Understanding immutability and virtual DOM in below case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, virtual-dom

After reading [here](https://reactkungfu.com/2015/08/pros-and-cons-of-using-immutability-with-react-js/) about immutability, I am trying to understand how react is working. I am trying to understand with the help of following 3 components, however its not making sense.

```js
const bla = {a: 1};
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: 1,
    };
    this.onClick = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
      a: prevState.a + 1
    }));
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Render default');
    return <div id="test" onClick = {
      this.onClick
    } > DOM Updating: {
      this.state.a
    } < /div>;
  }
}

class Test1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: 1,
    };
    this.onClick = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
      a: 1
    }));
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Render 1');
    return <div id="test1" onClick = {
      this.onClick
    } > DOM not updating: {
      this.state.a
    } < /div>;
  }
}

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = bla;
    this.onClick = () => {
      const mutating = this.state;
      mutating.a = this.state.a + 1;
      this.setState(mutating);
    };
  }
  render() {
    console.log('Render 2');
    return <div id="test2" onClick = {
      this.onClick
    } > DOM updating with mutation: {
      this.state.a
    } < /div>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( < div > < Test / > < Test1 / > < Test2 / > < /div>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If I inspect div id="test1" it is updating in Chrome dev tool on each click. Want to understand below points:

1. During on click If I inspect div id="text1" why this is not reflecting in dev tool? Here I am assigning new object in state on each click ({a: 1}). As the link above says

> In fact, React.js does not need to have knowledge about what exactly changed. All it needs to know is whether the state changed at all or not.

2. In Test2 component I am mutating the state however, why dom getting updated on click?
3. In case of [updating nested state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data) since we are updating parent state, does this mean React will think that all others children have changed their values and will re-render all of them even when they aren't changed?

Comment: In the first question, you mean `<div id="test1">`, don't you? Assumed that in my answer below for first point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) In the console output, you simply see `Render 1`, because you invoke `setState` with the static value `1`. But in fact, each time you invoke `setState` with the click, React will set a new (in the sence of new object reference) state for the component, and a new render cycle is triggered.

> setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

2.) See answer 1. In addition, you have a DOM change, because [state changes are merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged).

> When you call setState(), React merges the object you provide into the current state.

In your Test2 click handler code, mutating will be merged into the current state. It is the same object, but important is, that all its properties (here `a` property) will be spread into the state, resulting in a new state object.

```
const mutating = this.state;
mutating.a = this.state.a + 1;
this.setState(mutating);
```

3.) Let's say you have a `Parent` component containing all your child components. If you change `props` or `state` of `Parent`, all children will be rerendered by React, unless their `shouldComponentUpdate` hook returns false or they are `PureComponent`s, whose props or state did not change.

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Rerender means, that for each child, React compares the previous and the current version in a [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) step. It only leads to a DOM update, if the child has really changed, otherwise nothing happens. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action) for a nice visualization.

Comment: #1 still unanswered. Why the update isnt reflected in chrome dev tool? Or since the values are same Chrome dev tool wont show highlighted div :) ? And in background React updating both Virtual and Actual DOM?

Comment: #3 So "[React only updates what is necessary](https://react-legacy.netlify.com/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary)" is wrong?

Comment: @NatGeo #1 *is* reflected in the console. Every time, you click the second row, you get an additional `Render 1` in the stack snippet console (and in dev tools too). Everytime you click `render()` is invoked again, invoking your `console.log`. In this case, there are no DOM changes, as the contained `<div> ` still has the same text node with value `1` the whole time.

Comment: @NatGeo #3 the statement, that React is "lazy", is correct. Reconciliation = React diffs the previous and current version of the React Element. If it hasn't changed since last compare, React does nothing, only if change, there will be a DOM update triggered.

Comment: "because state changes are merged", does this mean we shouldn't take care of immutability? What does this mean when people say "if you mutate state then there wont be any way of finding what was the data before mutation"? I know what this mean, but I want to understand how react getting benefit of knowing what was the data earlier?

Comment: Immutability plays a role in React in the following ways: a) performance aspects b) change detection. For a) have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation). b) is not relevant for `setState` in class components - as described earlier, `setState` always triggers a rerender, after the method is invoked. Though In react hooks for example, React `useState` won't recognize a change, if you mutate the state directly and pass in the same object reference to it.